# Do I put 'const' in my UML diagram?

Tags: c++, uml

I'm making a UML diagram using [Dia](http://live.gnome.org/Dia). Do I need to put `const` in the diagram when a function is `const`? If so, where?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chapter 11.8.2 ("Operation") in the [latest UML specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.3/) lists **isQuery** as one of the operation's attributes:

> isQuery : Boolean  - Specifies whether an execution of the Operation leaves the state of the system unchanged (isQuery=true) or whether side effects may occur (isQuery=false). The default value is false.

If operation that does not change system's state is shown in a diagram, property **{query}** should be added after function's return type.

Dia supports **isQuery** attribute for class' operations: open class' *Properties* window and in *Operations* tab tick ***Query*** checkbox for method that does not change class' state and **const** will appear after method's return type in a diagram.

Comment: +1 My answer shouldn't be voted as the right one. You are 100% correct. Thank for the info.

Comment: Thank you Iulian. I've been reading recently UML standard and remembered that this property was mentioned there.

Comment: I modified my answer to point to yours. This way we avoid confusion for people searching the right answer for this question.